# Sonarlint not processing files due to analysis errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarlint-intellij

I am getting the following error when trying to process files in SonarLint

> "File won't be refreshed because there were errors during analysis:"
>
> Unfortunately SonarLint does not report which errors it is
>   encountering.  I set sonar.log.level to DEBUG and sonar.verbose to
>   true.

My project builds just fine and unit tests run.  I am running version 2.10.0.1922 of SonarLint and version 2017.1.4 of IntelliJ.  I have tried this on JDK 1.8.121 and JDK 1.8.131 but I get the same results.

Is there any way to retrieve what the errors are?  Am I missing something whith the logging parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-error-during-analysis-with-latest-intellij-and-remote-sonarqube-server/13440/7

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12836-choose-runtime -> and select java 8 runtime, e.g. [image: ![image|251x16](upload://fDCXVa9PzXO0GMhtob618juRHL4)] appears to work fine

Another solution is to upgrade SonarJava on the server to a version greater than 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Now I have an update in place en am finally getting some indication of what the problem was.  I should be able to take it from here.

So the issue is resolved by updating SonarLint